# How to dynamically change the size of the Canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

If the size of canvas set in the  MXML markup, some part of the components that go beyond the boundaries of canvas not displayed. If the canvas size to change dynamically(canvas.width, canvas.height), canvas boundaries are virtually absent. 
How to dynamically change the size of the Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a canvas? If you need sizes changed dinamically try to put your content inside a VBox for example ( of any **relative** container ) and use **minWidth**, **minHeight** to set it up, otherwise, Canvas is a component so is whould have width and height properties.

e.g.

```
<Canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300">
<!-- content here -- >
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

override the canvas's updateDisplayList function.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number,h:Number):void {
  super.updateDisplayList(w,h);
  this.setActualSize((child1.width+child2.width), Math.max(child1.height,child2.height));
}
```

Alternatives are to override the canvas measuredHeight/measuredWidth getters. Or override the "measure" function.

If scrolling is what you want, you have `horizontalSCrollPolicy`/`verticalScrollPolicy` properties of the canvas.

Lots of different solutions depending on your exact problem.